# How to get id of current draggable and resizable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get id of current draggable and resizable ?
I have like

```
$('.demo')
.resizable({
start:function(event,ui){
$(ui).item.attr('id);
}

})
.draggable({
start:function(event,ui){
$(ui).item.attr('id);
}
});
```

but it returns undefined. Does anyone know solution ?

Comment: **What** returns undefined? There's no code there that returns, or outputs, anything...

Answer (score 2):

You missed `'` symbol:

```
$(ui).item.attr('id');
```